# Importing classes in JupyterNotebooks

Tags: python, class, import, ipynb

I have a class system in one file and a file that uses it in another. They're both in the same folder. At the beginning of the file that uses the classes, I import the class file as well as both classes I need. Though the program runs and uses the classes correctly, VSStudio is underlining these imports in red and telling me that 'Import "filename" could not be resolved Pylance(reportMissingImports)'. I have no idea why this is happening, especially since it all compiles and runs correctly. Does anyone have any idea how I could fix this?

I've tried adding the classes to **all**, as well as using From filename import * instead of importing specific classes. I've also installed import_ipynb, so that's definitely not the issue (or at least, it really shouldn't be).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

can you share your folder structure.
and also the other folder should have the `__init__.py` file.

it should look something like this

```
other_folder
|___service
|       |_____package.py
|       |_____init__file.py
|___init__.py

working_folder
|___test.ipynb
```

in this ipynb file
call the package by

`from other_folder.service import package`

this should be able to solve your problem

Comment: I have the entire class in one file, is that not something I can do? So it's just class.ipynb and workingfile.ipynb

Comment: Yes if you have 2ipynb files then use the import_ipynb module.  `!pip install import_ipynb` Then in another cell `import import_ipynb
import /path/to/notebook`. Remember not to use the `.ipynb`  extension when writing the last import statement.  This is one of the way.  Another way would be running that class.ipynb file in the first cell of the working.ipynb. To do this use `%run /path/to/notebook.ipynb` see that is used the `%` operator and not `!` operator. Hope this will help you solve the problem.